# How to take a void method that takes readline and runs it though an array and assign it to a string variable

Tags: c#, string, console-application, void

Hello I have a console application that successfully runs input through an array containing Bad Words and if there is a bad word then it will output some text then quits the application. Now I want to see what I can do With DetectBW() Including assigning it to a string Although DetectBW() is a void type and it returns nothing so assigning it to a string isn't possible if it's written like this

EX.
string Name = DetectBW();

Here's my code for further explanation

```
namespace CleanApp
{
    class Application
    {
```

This region contains bad words. I wrote it in otherwise it says a whole list of bad words which wouldn't be good for obvious reason.

```
//profanityArray()
```

This region contains numbers 0-318 Including 318

```
//ProNumArray()
```

This is the Main method

```
#region//Main() Put everything thats finished in here to output it to Console Apllication.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Sarray = profanityArray();

            int[] Iarray = ProNum();
            // infinite loop that writes "Ask A question." then accepts a line of text from user (DetectBW())
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ask A question.");
                DetectBW();

            }


        }
        #endregion
```

This is the DetectBW() method it takes PlayerInput()string Method (Console.Readline) and runs it through the profanityArray and detects if PlayerInput() contains any of the bad words in profanityArray.

```
#region // DetectBW()
        static void DetectBW()

        {

            string PI = PlayerInput();

            string[] PIA = profanityArray();

            foreach(int i in ProNum())

            {

                if(PI.ToLower().Contains(PIA[i]))

                {

                    if (PI.ToLower().Contains(" "+PIA[i]+" "))

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(PI + " contains a bad word(s)!");

                        Console.WriteLine("If you can't be polite then get off!!");

                        Environment.Exit(0);

                        break;

                    }

                    if (PI.ToLower().Contains(PIA[i]+" ")|| PI.ToLower().Contains(" " + PIA[i]))

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(PI + " contains a bad word(s)!");

                        Console.WriteLine("If you can't be polite then get off!!");

                        Environment.Exit(0);

                        break;

                    }

                 }

             }

          }
        #endregion
```

This region is PlayerInput() it is the string method I was talking about.

```
#region// PlayerInput()
        static string PlayerInput()

        {

            string S = Console.ReadLine();

            return S;

        }
        #endregion
```

This is where I plan to to take the DetectBW() run it and take the same playerInput() used in DetectBW() and assign it to a string var for later use.

```
static void App()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is you name?");

            // This is where i need Help!!
        }

    }

}
```

So this is my question:
1.
I know that I can't assign a void to a string variable but is there a way to take the same playerInput() used in DetectBW(), so I know that there isn't any bad words in it, and assign it to a name string variable.

Comment: Hmm..change the method to return a list or array? I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: Why do you make it `void` if you need to return something?

Comment: Take the player input *outside* of `DetectBW` and pass it in instead - then you can use it outside of the method: `var input = // getplayerinput; DetectBW(input); DoOtherThingsWithInput(input);`

Comment: If the intention is to return some types, the signature should be changed to that (remove `void`). If you want to set the values in the `App` method, it can be assigned to a `static` type and used in `static` methods.

Comment: You could also use [Output Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(v=vs.71).aspx) , but i don't see what's the point